# how to create a file inside a folder using python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, file, os.path

i am trying to create a folder if is not exiting, then inside this folder i will create a file where the file is of **type JSON** and the file name is  **timestamp + searchResult.js**

where the result becomes:
**search_result/2018-4-7_searchResult.js**

the system display this error :

**expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType**

## code:

```
jsondata = json.dumps(listMetaData)

                    if not(os.path.exists('./search_result')):
                        try:
                            searchResultFoder=os.mkdir("./search_result")

                            today = datetime.date.today()
                            fileName = "{}_searchResult.js".format(today)
                            fpJ = os.path.join(searchResultFoder,fileName)
                            with open("{0}/{1}".format(fpJ,fileName),"w") as jsf:
                                jsf.write(jsondata)
                                print("finish writing")
                        except Exception as e:
                            print(e)
```

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

os.mkdir returns None, so your variable is getting initialized by None

```
searchResultFoder=os.mkdir("./search_result")
```

and when you do

```
fpJ = os.path.join(searchResultFoder,fileName)
```

It throws you the error. Simply store the path in a variable and use it

```
foldername = "./search_result"
fpJ = os.path.join(foldername,fileName)
```

Comment: i tried your answer but it display this error :

**[Errno 2] No such file or directory: './search_result\\2018-04-07_searchResult.js/2018-04-07_searchResult.js'**

Comment: fpj should be: ./search_result/2018-04-07_searchResult.js. Check if your variables are getting initialized properly

Comment: i tried to print  searchedResultFolder  and print fpJ

the result is 

**./search_result
./search_result\2018-04-07_searchResult.js**

Comment: but no folder or file were created

Comment: why are you doing this `with open("{0}/{1}".format(fpJ,fileName),"w")`? I think just doing `with open(fpJ,"w")` would do. This will create a file 2018-04-07_searchResult.js in folder ./search_result.

Comment: Just adding to this `.js` is the file extension for JavaScript, JSON uses `.json`

Comment: This is irrelevant to the problem though.

Comment: did not workk 

why the  print(os.mkdir("./search_result")) display None ?